# Magento 2 Add new column tracking/mobile number to sales grid

Tags: magento2, order-grid

Hello guys I need your help to know how to add new column "tracking/mobile number" to sales grid.

Comment: Try with this i haven't checked [this](https://rohitkundale.wordpress.com/2017/02/26/add-column-in-sales-invoice-order-grid-in-magento-2/) but please try.

Answer (score 0):

if this mobile column is already available in **sales_order_grid** table then just copy this file into you custom module `Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml` to `Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml`

Now inside `Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml` file add the below line.

```
<column name="mobile" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Mobile</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

the above code will come under-

```
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    ....
    .....
</columns>
```

**mobile** is column name in you database

Comment: Hi Mohammad, i tried this its show mobile field but empty. Do you have any idea how to call it?  Thank you

Comment: did you check if mobile field is available in **sales_order_grid** table.

Comment: No its not available in sales_order_grid table i found it inside sales_order_address table under telephone name So the question now how to tell xml file call data from sales_order_address

Comment: Joining two tables just for one field is not good idea instead add new column in **sales_order_grid** and insert the data in that column after order is placed.
still if you want to join you can refer this question.


https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123198/magento2-need-to-build-grid-with-multiple-table-collection-using-ui-components

Comment: I dont prefers this way also but i cant do it without joining. do you have any idea how to insert column from sales_order_address and sales_shipment_track to sales_order_grid to be able to call it inside order grid ?

Comment: You can catch the event sales_order_place_after from that event get the data u want and save in the table