# UI Component Listing - transform user ID to the user name

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, admin-user, listing-component

I've created a model management pages in admin by UI Component. When saving this model, the controller will save the `user id` of creator to the table then show this on the model listing page. It is simple to achieve:

```
<column name="creator_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Creator Id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

But, `user id` is difficult to distinguish. So, now I want to transform the **creator ID to the user Name**, how to achieve that?

> Notice the model table has the `user_id` column, but **doesn't** have the `user_name`. The UI Component need to use the `user_id` to get `user_name`, then put the name in the listing page.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Yes, see my answer below.

Comment: Yes but it is not working in filter. Any idea?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh See solution 2 in my answer - join table in collection

Comment: I used `_renderFiltersBefore` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution 2(better, can filter): join table in collection

In the `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName\Collection`, add the **_initSelect()** function like below

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('admin_user')],
        'main_table.creator_id = secondTable.user_id',
        ['username']
    );
}
```

If you want to join more tables or know more details about join tables, you could see my another answer [join multiple table in collection which build Admin Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/201607/44237)

---

In the UI Componet, add the `username` column

```
<column name="username">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">User Name</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

I think this is a **better solution** than solution 1. Because you could use the `username` column to filter collection.

---

### Solution 1(cannot filter): add class in UI Componet

In the UI Componet, add class for the creator_id:

```
<column name="creator_id"  class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CreatorName">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Creator Id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Create the class `Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CreatorName`, add the user name in the `public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)`. Whole codes is shown below:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\User\Model\UserFactory;

class CreatorName extends Column
{
    protected $userFactory;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     * @param UserFactory $userFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        UserFactory $userFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if ($item[$fieldName] != '') {
                    $adminName = $this->getAdminName($item[$fieldName]);
                    $item[$fieldName] = $item[$fieldName].' ('.$adminName.')';
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * @param $userId
     * @return string
     */
    private function getAdminName($userId)
    {
        $user = $this->userFactory->create()->load($userId);
        $name = $user->getName();
        return $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 solution is working but as said filters are not working but i tried 1 one but stll data is not fetching

$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('customer_entity')],
        'main_table.customer_id = secondTable.entity_id',
        ['firstname']